# Angular UI-Router, not found on URL refreshing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I type `http://localhost:6060/home`, it showed me cannot get `/home`, but when I click the button `$state.go('home')`, it shows, and the URL is still `http://localhost:6060/home`. But when I refresh, it stills does not show. How can it show when I type the URL?

Here are my code:

router.js

```
$stateProvider.state("home", {
    url: "/home",
    template: "<h2>I am a router test</h2>"
});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <title>for test</title>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body ng-app="my.module">
    <h1>I am just a test</h1>
    <div ng-controller="test"><button class="btn btn-default" 
         ng-click="testclick()">click me</button></div>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.testclick = function () {
   $state.go('home');
};
```

If I do not use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and not set `base` tag, I have to type `localhost:6060/#!/home`. What does the `!` mean?

Comment: can you add your `.config()` code?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/3208/angularjs-gotchas-and-traps/21798/things-to-do-when-using-html5mode#t=201702070409442702025

Answer (score 0):

Do you have server-side (PHP, Node.js, etc.)? To use `html5Mode(true)` you need server-side configuration, which forward all routes to the index page, therefore you can refresh the page without having the "Cannot get" error.

---

> What does the ! mean?

To understand this, you should read the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location): The exclamation mark character `!` is the hashbang mode, it is the default URL format and also the fallback for HTML5 Mode in legacy browsers.